# Google Chrome extension get IP address of server

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I had a good idea, which kind of revolves around ips from the server the user is on.

Im very new to making a google chrome extension, but i am good at the programming languages that requires to build one .

**Question**: Can I get a IP from a server that the user is on? and if so how would you do this?

I was thinking just AJAX the url to my own server which then pings the server which would get the ip and returns that/stores it some where.

Comment: I guess you need to do a DNS Lookup..

Comment: @Sudarshan Im just going to go with get the url of the page the user is on and then send it to my server and it will relay the data back.

Comment: Check my answer to fetch url of the page the user is on

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get current URL of `tab\web Page`user is currently browsing using [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) API

## Demonstration

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    "currentWindow": true, //Filters tabs in current window
    "status": "complete", //The Page is completely loaded
    "active": true // The tab or web page is browsed at this state,
    "windowType": "normal" // Filters normal web pages, eliminates g-talk notifications etc
}, function (tabs) { //It returns an array
    for (tab in tabs) {
        _url_i_need = tabs[tab].url;
        //Do AJAX Stuff here 
    }
});
```

Ensure you declare `tabs` permission in your manifest as shown here

```json
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  ...
}
```

## References

- [Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

Comment: hahaha, yer ive been messing around with that api, just couldn't get it working, ill try your code

Comment: This fetches the URL, but not the IP address.

Comment: Just as fafrd mentioned. It’s not giving the ID back.